# Does rootless Podman support varlink?

Tags: container, protocols, podman

I'm currently taking a look at a bunch of stuff with PodMan. One feature that I'd like is to be able to remotely interact with my pods—start and stop them from some other service.

I saw the Varlink API in [Programmatic remote access to Podman via the varlink protocol](https://podman.io/blogs/2019/01/16/podman-varlink.html), which is easy to consume in Java or Python. I need to run containers in rootless mode. Does anyone know if this is possible?